# List VMs - Google Compute Engine Node.js Client Library

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I get a list of all VMs when I exclude the keyFilename from Compute object's constructor.

```
const Compute = require('@google-cloud/compute');
const compute = new Compute();
const vms = await compute.getVMs(); // populated with right results
```

But as soon as I specify the keyFilename in Compute object's constructor, none of my VMs show up in result although they share the same Google Cloud Project ID as specified in the keyFilename.

```
const Compute = require('@google-cloud/compute');
const compute = new Compute({
    keyFilename: 'gcp.json'
});
const vms = await compute.getVMs(); // empty array
```

Please help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe it is a good idea to use an absolute path for the keyFilename and add the parameter

```
projectId: 'your-project-id'
```

to the constructor.

Besides that, your code looks pretty much vanilla so I see no problems, should work, according [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/compute/0.11.x/Compute).